# what and how to do unit test for angular factories

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Angular factory is great!! While writing unit test, it is kind of confusing, should we write unit test or not.

I have following factory:

```
(function(myApp) {
myApp.factory('MyFirstFactory', function(MySecondFactory){
  function MyFirstFactory(config){
    this.value1 = 'value1';
    setDefault(this);
  }

   MyFirstFactory.doSomething = function(){
     var config = {
       findWork: true;
       myWork: MySecondFactory.doWork()
     };
     return new MyFirstFactory(config);
   };

  return MyFirstFactory;
});
})(angular.module('MyModule'));
```

So for above factory, do we need to write unit test for MyFirstFacotry and doSomething function?
If yes, how can we achieve using jasmine and karma.. Tried following:

```
describe('MyFirstFactory', function() {
   var mockMyFirstFactory;
   beforeEach(function(){
     module('MyModule');
     inject(function(MyFirstFactory){
        mockMyFirstFactory = MyFirstFactory;
     });
   });

  it('MyFirstFactory should be defined', function(){
     expect(mockMyFirstFactory).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should do something', function(){
    // how to test doSomething 
  });
});
```

I am using jasmine, angular-mock, karma.

Answer (score 2):

Like all unit testing in general, you are scrutinizing the behavior of your code through tests. So if you have an expectation of something to have happened after you call `doSomething()`, you should have a test to reflect that expectation.

```
  it('should do something', function(){
    mockMyFirstFactory.doSomething(thing);
    expect(mockMyFirstFactory.somethingBool).toBe(true);
    expect(mockMyFirstFactory.somethingDone).toBe("some value");
    expect(mockMyFirstFactory.someMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Here is a snippet of a sample of one of our factories that we have built tests for for a simple general setup and test behavior.

```
    describe('imageUploader.imageModel module', function () {
        // VARIABLES
        var imageModel, imageModelFactory, $rootScope, sharedDataService;
        // INJECT AND SETUP DEPENDENCIES
        beforeEach(module('imageModel'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $injector, _imageModelFactory_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            sharedDataService = $injector.get('sharedDataService');
            imageModelFactory = _imageModelFactory_;
            spyOn($rootScope, '$apply');
        }));
        // SET UP MOCK DATA
        beforeEach(function () {
            sharedDataService.metadata = [{metadataItemOne: "one", metadataItemTwo: "two"}];
            var loadedData = {
                name: 'test_name.jpg',
                target: {
                    result: 'fakedata12345'
                }
            };
            var fake_file = {
                data: "fakedata12345",
                fileName: loadedData.name,
                fileType: "image",
                fileSize: 1024,
                fileDate: "7-7-2015"
            };
            imageModel = imageModelFactory(fake_file, loadedData);
        });
        // TEST BEHAVIOR
        it('can get an instance of imageModelFactory', function () {
            expect(imageModelFactory).toBeDefined();
        });
        it('can instantiate an instance of imageModel', function () {
            expect(imageModel).toBeDefined();
        });
        it('can set upload state', function () {
            imageModel.setUploaded(true);
            expect(imageModel.isUploaded).toBe(true);
            expect(sharedDataService.imagesSucceeded).toBe(1);
            imageModel.setUploaded(false);
            expect(imageModel.isUploaded).toBe(false);
            expect(sharedDataService.imagesSucceeded).toBe(0);
            expect(imageModel.RelatedToUpload).toHaveBeenCalled()
        });
    }
```

If all your are trying to figure out is how to do this with Jasmine, there is plenty of documentation and examples to get yourself started, like right here [Jasmine Spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies)

Comment: Thanks for explanation. In my example, i am wondering how to setup spy to test if  MySecondFactory.doWork() method have been called while testing for MyFirstFactory.doSomething.